# Calling external jar file like JTattoo.jar in your own created package

Tags: java, swing, jar, xml-parsing

How to call jar file from a class without using any IDE?

I'm trying to use functionality of `JTattooDemo.jar` in my own created folder named `lib` . How can I build path like IDE? And without using any command in CMD like `-cp` how can I develop my Swing application using only notepad?

Can I use .xml file to give path for .jar files if i have more .jar files?

Comment: Be specific on what you ask

Comment: *"PLZ.."* Please spell words properly, and don't SHOUT at us. *"..give detailed help.."*  SO is a Q&A site, not a help-desk *"..from starting to end... here is my code.."*  No it isn't.

Comment: actually i am using this site first time. and my english is so weak.

Comment: *"actually i am using this site first time."*  Yeah, that's pretty obvious, that's why I offered some advice & an answer rather than add a down vote, add a vote to close & ignore you.  Newbies would be well advised to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) & read through the docs in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)..

Answer (score 2):

The manifest file of a Jar can [specify the class-path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html).

You've tagged this with [swing](/questions/tagged/swing) so I'm guessing there is a Swing GUI in there somewhere.  The best way to deploy a Java desktop application is using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  Using JWS, the class-path can be specified in the JNLP file that launches the main app. (**or** the manifest file of the main Jar)